# meaning of symbols in terms of Siegel theta functions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $M$ be an even lattice of signature $ (b^{+},b^{-})$ , with dual $M'$ . We use  $v$ to denote an isometry from $M \otimes\textbf{R}$ to $\textbf{R}^{b^+,b^-}$ . We write $v^+$ and $v^-=v^{+\perp}$  for the inverse images of $\textbf{R}^{b^+,0}$ , $\textbf{R}^{0,b^-}$ under $v$ .
The projection of $\lambda \in M \otimes\textbf{R}$ into a subspace $v^{\pm}$ is denoted by $\lambda_{v^{\pm}}$ , so that $\lambda=\lambda_{v^+}+\lambda_{v^-}$ . Does someone know what $\textbf{R}^{b^+,b^-}$ means and how to find the inverse images of it under $v$ .

Thanks for the help .

Comment: Isn't it just that $2 |b|$ is the dimension of the target space?

Comment: I also think so , but how do the inverse images look like ?